# How to install Solr so jetty does not inflate its files?

Tags: java, linux, solr, installation, jetty

When I run java -jar start.jar, I get this directory structure:
`./mydir/work/Jetty_0_0_0_0_8984_solr.war__solr__.sltihw/webapp/WEB-INF/`

everything under `/work` has been inflated at run time.
However, the executing user will not have write permissions to the Solr installation directory, and so dynamic inflating will not work.

Is there a way to pre-inflate Jetty, or something like this?

Answer (score 0):

The unpacking of war files is controlled by the `org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext#extractWar(boolean)` method.

You can set this flag by using the [ContextDeployer](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/ContextDeployer), and setting that flag on the context configuration to false.  Note: this means you are no longer using the simple deployment of the [WebAppDeployer](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/WebAppDeployer) of dropping the war file into the webapps directory.

`<Set name="extractWAR">false</Set>`

See the jetty-distribution's `contexts/test.xml` for an example of the xml file.